spring boot backend container cannot connect to redis container internally in docker compose
I am sure that all containers are in the same network.
I can connect with redis-cli to redisContainer
If i start my spring boot app from ide (not in docker container), all fine
I only receive this error message below, without any particular explanations
I am sure that spring boot app receives correct env variables from compose file
I tried to remove "hosts: " from redis container, i tried to set REDIS_HOST to localhost in backend container
version: '3.8'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgresql_container
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: insight
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redisContainer
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  backend:
    build: .
    container_name: backendContainer
    ports:
      - "8081:8082"
    environment:
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      REDIS_HOST: redis

      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/insight
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: admin

    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always

volumes:
  postgres_data:



application.yaml

spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  redis:
    host: ${REDIS_HOST}
    port: ${REDIS_PORT}
server:
  port: 8082


logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.data.redis: DEBUG

The error message:

2024-12-23 18:36:48 2024-12-23T15:36:48.226Z ERROR 1 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet 
[dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: 
Unable to connect to Redis] with root cause
2024-12-23 18:36:48 
2024-12-23 18:36:48 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946) ~[na:na]
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:336) ~[netty-transport-4.1.114.Final.jar!/:4.1.114.Final]
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:339) ~[netty-transport-4.1.114.Final.jar!/:4.1.114.Final]
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776) ~[netty-transport-4.1.114.Final.jar!/:4.1.114.Final]
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.114.Final.jar!/:4.1.114.Final]
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.114.Final.jar!/:4.1.114.Final]
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.114.Final.jar!/:4.1.114.Final]
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.114.Final.jar!/:4.1.114.Final]
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.114.Final.jar!/:4.1.114.Final]
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.114.Final.jar!/:4.1.114.Final]
2024-12-23 18:36:48     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
2024-12-23 18:36:48

I have these two dependencies about redis

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

i have no redis configs, the app works fine with redis if it is started not from container

For starters your backend container doesn't depend on the redis container, so it won't wait for it to be started.

i just had to go spring.data.redis.host ...  instead of spring.redis.host ...  cuz of spring boot 3.x
